# Subtraction of repeating values from Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wpfdatagrid

I have the following Datagrids as shown in the picture below.

I have the sales of 3 similar Items bearing the same ItemCode in Sales Datagrid whose sum amounts to 4.

The current stock of that particular Item is 20.

When I click the validate button, I'm using the following query to subtract the Sales from Current Stock and hence updating the Transaction History Datagrid.

**Query :**

```
var changes = (from dr1 in dtItemSales.AsEnumerable()
               from dr2 in dtItemStock.AsEnumerable()
               where dr1.Field<string>("ItemCode") == dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode"),
                           Remarks = dr2.Field<int>("Qty") - dr1.Field<int>("Quantity")
                       }).Distinct().ToList();


//Updating the Transaction History DataGrid.
dgTransactionHistory.ItemsSource = changes;
```

[image]

> My problem here is that when I am subtracting the Sales from Current
>   Stock **I am getting 2 records bearing the same ItemCode with 2 different values 19 and 18**.
>
> I should be getting **only 1 record with the value 16** in this particular case. 
>   *(20 - 2 - 1 - 1)*

Any help regarding this query would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should group by records with itemcode and then do sum of questities for sales and purchase. and then do subtraction.

Comment: Downvoters please state your clarification for downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should be getting **only 1 record with the value 16** in this particular case. *(20 - 2 - 1 - 1)*

First try to get the sum of `Quantity` from `dtItemSales` with particular `ItemCode` that matches to `dtItemStock` item code.

And then subtract the above sum with `dtItemStock`s `Qty` column like

So your final query look like

```
var changes = (from dr1 in dtItemSales.AsEnumerable()
               from dr2 in dtItemStock.AsEnumerable()
               where dr1.Field<string>("ItemCode") == dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")
               let sum = dtItemSales.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ItemCode") == dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")).Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("Quantity"))
               select new
               {
                   Name = dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode"),
                   Remarks = dr2.Field<int>("Qty") - sum
               }).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

**Output from Debugger:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. Working like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the highlighted Item in your question, the results will be 18 and 19 (2 results). Why?
Because Stock has 1 record with value 20. In the Where clause on your LINQ

You get 3 differences when you doing Stock - Sales:

20 - 2, 20 -1 & another 20 - 1 (for the 3 sales)

=> 18, 19, 19

Now at the end you have a Distinct - which is why one 19 is thrown and you get 18 & 19.

Why dont you SUM all the Sales grouping on the ItemId first. Then Substract from Stock.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification regarding the .Distinct()
You mean to sum all the Sales in the sales item then subtract it from the current stock table.

Comment: Yes. If you need help with it - please share the Minimal structure for Sales & Stock classes. I will try & come up with LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for your help bro. Much appreciated.

Comment: Wondering why you downvoted the question even though I voted for your answer.